# use map for J2me application

Tags: google-maps, mobile, java-me, gis

i am developing a tracking system for mobile using j2me and **i want a library free library to deal with maps where i can scroll the map, chose position and get longitude and latitude to my application.**

*static Google map is limited to 1000 request and no scrollable features for it.*

Comment: What mobile OS are you writing this for? BlackBerry? Android?